# Problems regarding Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Given that $f(x) = x^2$, I got that the Fourier series is
$$
x^2 = \dfrac{\pi^2}{3} + \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot 4 \cdot \dfrac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}
$$
for $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$. From the above series, how can I find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Consider $x = \pi$ and then $x = 0$. Then, add the two results and see what you get.

Comment: thank you... Yes I got that answer... Can You please tell me how to get the summation of 1/n^4 from the above series?